# Site on Firefox make issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, frameworks

I'm doing a site ,i'm trying it on chrome and it works well. When i use it on firefox it make all bigger than usual and it also don't recognise the webkit(transition,filter). I think that the problem can be solved with some framework but i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard properties (which have been supported for ages) instead of the vendor prefixed experimental versions.